# How to check a type for parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, constructor

Because I want to avoid an exception, I want to check whether a type has a parameterless constructor. How can I achieve this?

I need something like this:

```
bool HasDefaultConstructor<TT>(TT source)
{
   return ???;
}
```

EDIT:
I want to create an object of same type as source and if it hasn't a default constructor I want to use default(TT) instead.

What I have right now is:

```
        static TT CreateObject<TT>(TT source)
    {
        try
        {
            if(!HasDefaultConstructor<TT>(source))
            {
                return default(TT);
            }
            return (TT)Activator.CreateInstance(source.GetType());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("Exception catched!\r\n" + ex);
        }
        return default(TT);
    }
    static bool HasDefaultConstructor<TT>(TT source)
    {
        ConstructorInfo c = typeof(TT).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });

        return c != null;
    }
```

But the check gives me true and CreateInstance throws exception

> No parameterless constructor

Solution:

```
bool HasDefaultConstructor(Type t)
{
   return t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;
}
```

There were many recursive functions and iterations involved and somewhere down this way, the wrong generic function HasDefaultConstructor (with type object) has been called. Using a non generic function did the trick.

Thank you all for your constructive help.

Comment: Please clarify your question - how do you want to invoke the constructor? As you expect an exception if there is no parameterless constructor, I take it you want the code still compileable even if the type indicated for `TT` does not have such a constructor?

Comment: If there is no default constructor I want to use default(TT) instead.

Comment: Aha! Then please, include that information in your question. It significantly changes the meaning of the question and renders any answers referring to the `new()` generic constraint invalid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)` will return the parameterless constructor, or null if one does not exist, so you can have:

```
return typeof(TT).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;
```

**EDIT**

I'm guessing your problem is that `TT` and `source.GetType()` are actually two different types. `source.GetType()` probably derives from `TT` but has no parameterless constructor. So what you actually need to do is make the check for `source.GetType()`:

```
bool HasDefaultConstructor(Type t)
{
   return t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null;
}

if(!HasDefaultConstructor(source.GetType()))
    ...
```

Comment: You are right. Somewhere on the way through some recursive functions the information about the type got lost. So the generic functions for object (an not for the real type) were called and indeed GetType and TT were not the same. Using source.GetType() helped.

Answer (score 9):

Use reflection to check if the type has a parameterless constructor. Use [`Type.GetConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
bool HasDefaultConstructor<TT>()
{
    ConstructorInfo c = typeof(TT).GetConstructor(new Type[] { });
    // A constructor without any types defined: no parameters

    return c != null;
}
```

If you just want to create an instance of `TT`, use the `new` constraint:

```
TT CreateUsingDefaultConstructor<TT>() where TT : new()
{
    return new TT();
}
```

---

As [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1336654/jeppe-stig-nielsen) suggested, you could use this code to also find constructors that are not `public`. In my opinion, you should only use this as a last resort!

```
typeof(TT).GetConstructor( BindingFlags.Instance
                           | BindingFlags.NonPublic
                           | BindingFlags.Public
                         , null
                         , new Type[] { }
                         , null
                         )
```

Comment: Of course, if you also accept a non-public zero-parameter constructor as well, try `typeof(TT).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public, null, new Type[] { }, null)`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Added your suggestion to the answer, with attribution.

Comment: Your version of HasDefaultConstructor gives me true, but the following CreateInstance throws exception.

Comment: @MTR: Do you have a sample class?

Comment: @MTR: Also don't use `source`, use `typeof(TT)`.

Comment: @MTR: See my answer. It doesn't use `source`.

Comment: I'm working on a sample, as this seems to work in simple cases, but not in my case.

Comment: @MTR: I see. So it was `source` after all. Told you so ;)